# Web scraping many URLs and writing to Excel file

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to scrape 20000 URLs, each web page containing a table of information. Essentially each web page is like a combo, and it has several items, each item having a description. I am scraping two elements - `item`, `description` from each row in the table for all the 20000+ combos.

I will then write this information to an excel file. Each row represents a combo, with the first cell of each row containing the URL of the combo. The header of the file contains the variables `item` . So for a particular combo (a particular row number) and a particular `item` (a particular column), there is a `description`. Any two combos could have some `item` in common; they could also have some `item` not in common. So I want to have an exhaustive list of all `item`s available in my excel file header.

So for each row in a web page, I first check if the `item` already existed in my excel header.

```
have = False  #boolean to check if the header already contains the name 
item_position = 1  #if found, find out its column number 

for cell in list(ws1.rows)[0]:

        value = cell.value
        val = value.encode('utf-8')
        if item == val:
                have = True
                break
        else:
                item_position += 1
```

If so then I will note down the column number and put `description` accordingly; if not I will append the `item` to the next empty cell in the header `empty_header_cell` and note down the column number and put `description`.

However, after like less than hundred URLs scraped, the speed becomes drastically slower. I think it is both due to web page requesting as well as finding existing `item`? I wonder if there is any improvement to the code to speed up the process. Here is my complete code:

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook


wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Destination.xlsx')
ws1=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
empty_header_cell = 2  
#maintains the column number of the next empty cell in the excel file header

with open ('urls.csv') as f:
f_csv = csv.reader(f)
header = next(f_csv)
row_number = 2 #maintains a row number which increments after each url is scraped


for row in f_csv:
        url = row[0]

        ws1.cell(row=row_number, column=1).value = url
        wb.save(filename="Destination.xlsx")  

        try:
            page = requests.get(url)
            web = page.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(web, 'lxml')


            table = soup.find('table', {'class': "tc_table"})  #find the table in each web page that I am goinf to scrape
            trs = table.find_all('tr')


            for tr in trs:

                    ls = []
                    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
                            ls.append(td.text)
                    ls = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in ls]

                    try:
                            item = ls[1]
                            description = ls[2]

                            have = False  #boolean to check if the header already contains the name 
                            item_position = 1  #if found, find out its column number 

                            for cell in list(ws1.rows)[0]:

                                    value = cell.value
                                    val = value.encode('utf-8')
                                    if item == val:
                                            have = True
                                            break
                                    else:
                                            item_position += 1

                            if have == True:   #if item found
                                    ws1.cell(row=row_number, column=item_position).value = description
                                    wb.save(filename = 'Destination.xlsx')

                           elif have == False: #if item not found
                                    ws1.cell(row=1, column=empty_header_cell).value = item       #append item to the next empty header cell                               
                                    ws1.cell(row=row_number, column=empty_header_cell).value = description
                                    empty_header_cell += 1 #update next empty header cell
                                    wb.save(filename = 'Destination.xlsx')

                    except IndexError:
                            print("i am an IndexError")


            row_number += 1  #start scraping the next url

        except IndexError:  #to skip those webpages that have slightly different format so data cannot be located
                print("skipping this website")    
                row_number += 1                
        except AttributeError:
                print("attribute error")
                row_number += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me take it from the performance perspective.

#### The main bottleneck

*You are scraping the pages sequentially in the blocking manner* - processing urls one at a time, not proceeding to the next url until you are done with the current one.

There are a number of tools that can help to switch to an asynchronous strategy. Look into [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) web-scraping framework. There is also [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is based on `AsyncIO`.

#### Gathering scraping results

I think you don't actually need an Excel writer here since you are only writing simple text data - you are not concerned with advanced data types or workbook style and formatting. **Use a CSV writer** - Python has a built-in [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Note that if you'll switch to `Scrapy`, you'll get the [built-in CSV exporter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720510/771848) "for free".